# SSH does not work when ssh from user A host1 to user B host2 then B host3

Tags: ssh

Please help with the following issue:

I have 2 users **A** and **B** and 3 hosts **HOST1**, **HOST2**, **HOST3**.

I am user **A** at **HOST1**.

ssh **B@HOST2** works fine. **A@HOST1 -> B@HOST2**

ssh **B@HOST3** works fine. **A@HOST1 -> B@HOST3**

But
ssh **B@HOST2** then ssh **B@HOST3** does not work. 
**A@HOST1 ->(works) B@HOST2 ->(does not work ) B@HOST3**

I got this:

debug1: Reading configuration data /home/B/.ssh/config

debug1: /home/B/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *

debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config

debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 50: Applying options for *

debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0

debug1: Connecting to **HOST3** [***.***.***.***] port 22.

debug1: connect to address [***.***.***.***] port 22: Connection timed out

ssh: connect to host **HOST3** port 22: Connection timed out

Thank you in advance,

Philipp

Comment: Have you added `~/id_rsa.pub` of `B@HOST2` in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file of  `B@HOST3`?

Comment: I have tried, but it does not help.

Comment: @sajibkhan problems with the key wouldn't cause a connection timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeasers that firewall blocks it.